# ClickOnce application not showing anything after launching

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have publish **ClickOnce** application in file network. After installing application and there is created shortcut.

When I launch application nothing happens, there is glimpse of process in task manager and nothing happens.

But some of my other ClickOnce application works fine. 
Only that application does nothing. 
I have no idea what is happening, no error, nothing. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Have you looked into the Eventlog of your system, ClickOnce often writes the exceptions into this.

Comment: Could be a million reasons. Try following the advice here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-specify-verbose-log-files-for-clickonce-deployments?view=vs-2017)  and turn on verbose ClickOnce logging. ClickOnce doesnt write detailed errors to the event Log but does write out a detailed log file which I've always found extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click once application gets installed locally in this path - 
`c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\obfuscatedfoldername\obfuscatedfoldername`

You can go to this path - by typing in run command: `%appdata%\..\Local\Apps\2.0`

Delete the contents of this folder and re-open the click once to re-install it.

- Check if the application gets freshly installed.
- Try opening from that location directly.
- If the application has logs, check it
- If not check the event log for clues.